# Как изменить стиль - Html::error?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как я могу изменить стиль вывода ошибок **Html::error** в **Yii-2**? 
Я хочу сделать вот такой стиль:

```
<div style="backgraund-color: blue; hieght:30px; width: 30px;">Error - ........</div>
```

---

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= Html::activeTextInput($model, 'password') ?>

<?= Html::error($model, 'password') ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Даже не знаю, как в Yii-2 выводятся ошибки, но может быть как-то так: `<div style="background-color: blue; hieght:30px; width: 30px;">Error - <?php Html::error($model, 'password'); ?></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Если под стилем имеются в виду css стили получаемого тэга, то у хелперов обычно последним параметром указываются html опции:

```
Html::error($model, 'password', ['class' => 'my-error'])
```

И соотв-но стилями менять все как нужно.
Если нужно текст сообщений об ошибках как-то изменять, то смотря как, приписать "Error -" можно и через :before теми же стилями, или наваять свой аналог хелпера (там по сути 3 строки кода через $model->getFirstError).

update: в общем если хочется управления формой, но при этом остаться в рамкам коробочной клиентской валидации yii, то я делал как-то так:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->begin() ?>
  <?= Html::activeTextInput($model, 'password', ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
  <?= Html::error($model, 'password', ['class' => 'help-block my-class']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->end(); ?>
```

Comment: 1.Изменить стиль password при условии если есть ошибка. 2.Изменить сам стиль того места, где выводится ошибка, при условии если есть ошибка.